# How to check if char* only has hex characters in C?

Tags: c

I have a `char *argv[]` that I want to check only contains valid hex values. For example I'm trying to write a function like `bool isHex(argv[1])` and says if it only has hex. How do I ensure that it only has numbers 0-9 and letters a-f? I've found ways for all alpha or numbers but I'm not sure if there's an easier way for hex. Thanks.

Comment: "I've found ways for all alpha or numbers but I'm not sure if there's an easier way for hex". When posting questions, make sure to include your understanding on the matter. Although I already answered, my answer could better fit you if I had some more context.

Comment: "... and letters a-f".  What about `'A'` to `'F'`?

Answer (score 2):

You can check a string's contents *vs*. any set of characters via the standard [`strspn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) function.  It computes the length of the initial segment of a specified string that consists exclusively of the specified characters:

```
unsigned hex_count = strspn(arg, "0123456789abcdef");
_Bool is_all_hex = !arg[hex_count];    // is arg[hex_count] a string terminator?
```

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonably performant solution, you can use a static lookup table:

```
#include <limits.h>

int isHex(char c)
{
    static int s_hex_digit[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {
        ['0'] = 1, ['1'] = 1, ['2'] = 1, ['3'] = 1, ['4'] = 1,
        ['5'] = 1, ['6'] = 1, ['7'] = 1, ['8'] = 1, ['9'] = 1,
        ['A'] = 1, ['B'] = 1, ['C'] = 1, ['D'] = 1, ['E'] = 1, ['F'] = 1,
        ['a'] = 1, ['b'] = 1, ['c'] = 1, ['d'] = 1, ['e'] = 1, ['f'] = 1
    };
    return s_hex_digit[(unsigned char)c];
}
```

This comes at the expense of some static memory, but not too much.  Changing the array element type of `s_hex_digit` to `char` instead of `int` will save a bit of memory, which might work better with caches if you are doing this a lot.

It has the benefit of having no branching (a performance consideration), but also working with any character encoding (*e.g.* non-ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

Read them as numbers: its value should be

- between 48 (char 0) and 57 (char 9)
- between 65 (char A) and 70 (char F)
- between 97 (char a) and 102 (char f)

(values taken from an ASCII table, such as this: http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Try `isxdigit()`, defined in `<ctype.h>`, which will match the digits 0 through 9 and the uppercase and lowercase letters A to F. On BSD and macOS, you can also use `ishexnumber()`

Comment: You meant to say `isxdigit()` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isxdigit ... `ishexnumber` is not a standard function.

Comment: `ishexnumber()` is non-standard.  It seems to be a BSD-ism, and somewhat unusual among those in that glibc has not picked it up.